# How to insert a space between a number and a string in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using the java.util.scanner feature in Java (awesome!) but I have yet to figure out how to scan numbers that have units attached. For example, I know that you can insert spaces between numbers and non-numeric characters so that "47mg" becomes "47 mg". That would solve it for most situations. However, none of the solutions I have found so far seem to handle numbers that have exponents in them (scientific/engineering notation). For example, I would like it to convert "47E-3mg" to "47E-3 mg". Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Update: Here is more background. In C++ the  class has a feature that is similar to the scanner bit it knows where a number stops and does not give an error if a string is attached. It just stops where the number stops. Here is a simple example in C++:

```
istringstream myStream;
string tempString;
double tempDouble;
string myString = " USE 1.23E-3mg ";
myStream.str(myString);
myStream >> tempString;
cout << "String:" << tempString << ":" << endl;
myStream >> tempDouble;
cout <<"Double:"<<tempDouble<<endl;
myStream >> tempString;
cout << "String:" << tempString << ":" << endl;
return 0;
```

It will output:
String:USE:
Double:0.00123
String:mg:

Update 2: Based on one of the answers I think the solution is close. Here is what we have now. It almost works. Just need to handle multiple entries... Anyone see what can be changed?

```
//String myString = "1.23E-3"; //Works
//String myString = "1.23E-3mg"; //Works
//String myString = "1.23E-3g"; //Works
String myString = "1.23mg 1.23mg";
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("([a-z]+)$", " 
$1"));
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions to get a number. Or find unit in the right part (get letters from last to first symbol until you get a digit). Then add a space.

Comment: How will your code know whether the E is a unit and need to add a space, or part of the number? Can we say that E followed by a letter needs a space but not an isolated E?

Comment: The issue is that 1.23E-3 is all one number so just looking for a digit is not enough I think. What I was hoping for was that the .nextDouble() function would stop where the double stop. But it returns an error if the double has a string attached. So I need to prepare the string first by adding spaces as described above.

Comment: Yes, the issue here is to have a function that is smart and knows that 1.23, 1.23E-3 both are numbers. the nextDouble() will handle it but not if the number is 1.23E-3mg... hence the question.

Comment: A piece of well-intentioned advice: let the user only enter numbers and then add the unit. Anything else can easily become a nightmare.

Comment: Added an update with more background and a comparison to the <istringstream> class in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you had the following:

```
String [] data = {"43E-2mg", "96.2mg", "55cc"};
```

This lets you replace one or more characters at then end of a string with a space and those same characters.

```
for (String s : data) {
    s = s.replaceAll("([a-z]+)$", " $1");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

prints

```
43E-2 mg
96.2 mg
55 cc
```

If you want to capture the individual parts for extra processing you can split on the zero width gap between the amount and the unit.

- `(?<![a-z])` - not preceded by `a-z`
- `(?=[a-z]+$)` - followed by one or more `a-z` followed by a new line.

```
for (String s : data) {
    String[] parts = s.split("(?<![a-z])(?=[a-z]+$)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

prints

```
[43E-2, mg]
[96.2, mg]
[55, cc]
```

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm! I test it with:  String [] data = {"1.23", "1.23E-3", "1.23E-3mg", "1.23E-3g", "1.23e-3g"}; and it worked for all of them!!! Thanks again!!

Comment: I spoke too early... What needs to be changed for it to do it with all numbers in a string? 
//String myString = "1.23E-3"; //Works
//String myString = "1.23E-3mg"; //Works
//String myString = "1.23E-3g"; //Works
String myString = "1.23mg 1.23mg"; // Does not work. Returns 1.23mg 1.23 mg
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("([a-z]+)$", " $1"));

Comment: Thanks again! This will do. I will just modify my code to work on one number at a time rather than modifying the entire string in one-go. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("47E-3mg");
sb.insert(sb.indexOf("mg"), " "); //insert(index, string)
System.out.println(sb);
```

Output: 47E-3 mg

Comment: Thanks! I have yet to try out the StringBuilder. It seems great! The issue here is that I don' know what is in the string (it is user input). It could be "mg", "ug", or "g" for example. But the answer above solved it. Thanks for the heads up on the StringBuilder as I have hard about it before!

Comment: @user3582742 It shouldn't be "ug" but rather "µg" or "mcg".